Fasttext pre-trained model is not producing OOV word vectors when using gensim downloader
I am having A LOT of trouble when trying to use all the fasttext libraries (in Jupyter with Anaconda3 on Windows 11) that I have found so far but this question is mainly about gensim's implementation. I simply can't get it to work for me.
Python version
3.9.12 (main, Apr  4 2022, 05:22:27) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
Version info.
sys.version_info(major=3, minor=9, micro=12, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
In gensim 4.3.2. the only thing that kind of worked for me was using
import gensim.downloader as api
fasttext_model300 = api.load('fasttext-wiki-news-subwords-300')

The model at least was loaded, however if I try getting the word vectors of OOV words such as fasttext_model300['nonexistentword'] I get a key error which should not happen with fasttext. This was very disappointing... So is this "model" the same as using the downloadable .vec file?
I also downloaded the bin file for the model and tried:
from gensim.models import FastText as ft
fasttext_model=ft.load_fasttext_format('path/crawl-300d-2M-subword/crawl-300d-2M-subword.bin')

But I got:
2024-05-27 21:07:10,790 : ERROR : failed to decode invalid unicode bytes b'DeutschHrvatskiEnglishDanskNederlandssuomiFran\xc3\xa7ais\xce\x95\xce\xbb\xce\xbb\xce'; replacing invalid characters, using 'DeutschHrvatskiEnglishDanskNederlandssuomiFrançaisΕλλ\\xce'
2024-05-27 21:07:12,269 : ERROR : failed to decode invalid unicode bytes b'\xe3\x81\x99\xe3\x81\xb9\xe3\x81\xa6\xe3\x81\xae\xe5\x9b\x9e\xe7\xad\x94\xe3\x82\x92\xe9\x9d\x9e\xe8\xa1\xa8\xe7\xa4\xba\xe3\x81\xab\xe3\x81\x99\xe3\x82\x8b\xe8\xb3\xaa\xe5\x95\x8f\xe3\x82\x92\xe5\x89\x8a\xe9\x99\xa4\xe3\x81\x97\xe3'; replacing invalid characters, using 'すべての回答を非表示にする質問を削除し\\xe3'
2024-05-27 21:07:13,692 : ERROR : failed to decode invalid unicode bytes b'00Z\xe9\x83\xa8\xe5\xb1\x8b\xe3\x82\xbf\xe3\x82\xa4\xe3\x83\x97\xe3\x81\xbe\xe3\x82\x8b\xe3\x81\xbe\xe3\x82\x8b\xe8\xb2\xb8\xe5\x88\x87\xe5\xbb\xba\xe7\x89\xa9\xe3\x82\xbf\xe3\x82\xa4\xe3\x83\x97\xe4\xb8\x80\xe8\xbb\x92\xe5'; replacing invalid characters, using '00Z部屋タイプまるまる貸切建物タイプ一軒\\xe5'
2024-05-27 21:07:13,734 : ERROR : failed to decode invalid unicode bytes b'2017\xe6\x88\xbf\xe9\x97\xb4\xe7\xb1\xbb\xe5\x9e\x8b\xe7\x8b\xac\xe7\xab\x8b\xe6\x88\xbf\xe9\x97\xb4\xe6\x88\xbf\xe6\xba\x90\xe7\xb1\xbb\xe5\x9e\x8b\xe7\x8b\xac\xe7\xab\x8b\xe5\xb1\x8b\xe5\x8f\xaf\xe4\xbd\x8f2\xe5\x8d'; replacing invalid characters, using '2017房间类型独立房间房源类型独立屋可住2\\xe5\\x8d'
2024-05-27 21:07:13,901 : ERROR : failed to decode invalid unicode bytes b'2016\xe6\x88\xbf\xe9\x97\xb4\xe7\xb1\xbb\xe5\x9e\x8b\xe7\x8b\xac\xe7\xab\x8b\xe6\x88\xbf\xe9\x97\xb4\xe6\x88\xbf\xe6\xba\x90\xe7\xb1\xbb\xe5\x9e\x8b\xe7\x8b\xac\xe7\xab\x8b\xe5\xb1\x8b\xe5\x8f\xaf\xe4\xbd\x8f2\xe5\x8d'; replacing invalid characters, using '2016房间类型独立房间房源类型独立屋可住2\\xe5\\x8d'
2024-05-27 21:07:15,714 : ERROR : failed to decode invalid unicode bytes b'00Z\xe9\x83\xa8\xe5\xb1\x8b\xe3\x82\xbf\xe3\x82\xa4\xe3\x83\x97\xe3\x81\xbe\xe3\x82\x8b\xe3\x81\xbe\xe3\x82\x8b\xe8\xb2\xb8\xe5\x88\x87\xe5\xbb\xba\xe7\x89\xa9\xe3\x82\xbf\xe3\x82\xa4\xe3\x83\x97\xe5\x88\xa5\xe8\x8d\x98\xe5'; replacing invalid characters, using '00Z部屋タイプまるまる貸切建物タイプ別荘\\xe5'
2024-05-27 21:07:17,849 : ERROR : failed to decode invalid unicode bytes b'\xe6\xb6\x88\xe8\xb2\xbb\xe8\x80\x85\xe7\x9f\xa5\xe9\x81\x93\xe4\xb8\x80\xe5\x80\x8b\xe8\xa3\xbd\xe9\x80\xa0\xe5\x95\x86\xe5\x85\xb6\xe4\xb8\xad\xe4\xb8\x80\xe5\x80\x8b\xe7\x94\xa2\xe5\x93\x81\xe7\x9a\x84\xe4\xb8\x80\xe8\x88\xac\xe5'; replacing invalid characters, using '消費者知道一個製造商其中一個產品的一般\\xe5'
2024-05-27 21:07:18,053 : ERROR : failed to decode invalid unicode bytes b'\xce\xb9\xce\xb4\xce\xb9\xce\xbf\xce\xba\xcf\x84\xce\xb7\xcf\x83\xce\xaf\xce\xb1\xcf\x82\xce\x94\xce\xb9\xce\xb1\xce\xbc\xce\xad\xcf\x81\xce\xb9\xcf\x83\xce\xbc\xce\xb1\xce\x86\xcf\x84\xce\xbf\xce\xbc\xce\xb12\xce\xa5\xcf\x80\xce'; replacing invalid characters, using 'ιδιοκτησίαςΔιαμέρισμαΆτομα2Υπ\\xce'
2024-05-27 21:07:18,202 : ERROR : failed to decode invalid unicode bytes b'\xe6\x88\x96\xe5\x85\xb6\xe4\xbb\x96\xe5\xae\x98\xe6\x96\xb9\xe7\x82\xb9\xe8\xaf\x84\xe6\x94\xb6\xe9\x9b\x86\xe5\x90\x88\xe4\xbd\x9c\xe4\xbc\x99\xe4\xbc\xb4\xe6\x8f\x90\xe4\xbe\x9b\xe7\x9a\x84\xe5\xb7\xa5\xe5\x85\xb7\xe9\xbc\x93\xe5'; replacing invalid characters, using '或其他官方点评收集合作伙伴提供的工具鼓\\xe5'
2024-05-27 21:07:18,245 : ERROR : failed to decode invalid unicode bytes b'00Z\xe6\x88\xbf\xe9\x96\x93\xe9\xa1\x9e\xe5\x9e\x8b\xe7\xa7\x81\xe4\xba\xba\xe6\x88\xbf\xe9\x96\x93\xe6\x88\xbf\xe6\xba\x90\xe9\xa1\x9e\xe5\x9e\x8b\xe5\xae\xb6\xe5\xba\xad\xe5\xbc\x8f\xe6\x97\x85\xe9\xa4\xa8\xe5\x8f\xaf\xe4'; replacing invalid characters, using '00Z房間類型私人房間房源類型家庭式旅館可\\xe4'

Eventually my laptop got a memory error and crashed which suggests I lack the RAM to do this but in any case this decoding error seems like actual Chinese to me...
Would the above work somehow if I upgraded my laptop's RAM, for example?
Any suggestions would be HUGELY appreciated.

Yes, a properly-loaded full FastText model should give synthesized vectors for OOV words.
I recommend against using the gensim.downloader' utility. Its operation obscures the original sources & raw formats of used data, and also hides which Gensim functions and classes are being used to complete the .load()`. Further, its functionality depends on loading and executing small shims of extra source code from outside the built, versioned, PyPI-hosted official release packages.
If you instead download the data from its original source, you'll see the packaging/format choices of its publisher, and get to make your own decision about where the files land. Then, it's rarely more than 2-3 lines of code, directly using the relevant well-documented Gensim calls, to explicitly load the specific data & model-types you need.
So, your second approach is on the right track, let's consider what might have gone wrong.
Note that the FastText.load_fasttext_model() method is marked in the Gensim docs as deprecated (use is discouraged) in favor of the more-specific methods .load_facebook_vectors() (when you want to use a .bin file but only need the full-word-vectors) or .load_facebook_model() (when you want the full model with the ability to synthesize OOV words). Still, the discouraged method still forwards to the one you want, .load_facebook_model(), so it shouldn't be the source of problems.
If a mere call to .load_facebook_model(), with your desired model as the target, goes wrong with the "failed to decode" errors you're seeing, that implies something is amiss with the exact crawl-300d-2M-subword.bin file that you're trying to load.
I would double-check each step that preceded that file being where you wanted to work with it:

is it from the right website?
did it download without any error/trucation? (does re-downloading result in an idnetical received file?)
did any unpacking of the download into constituent files proceed without error or corruption?
has any other reprocessing or transfer of the files caused corruption?

It looks from the filename like your model may have originally come from https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/english-vectors.html – and I'd expect a .bin file direct from the Facebook team to be in the proper format. So the "faield to decode" errors are surprising, and might go away if you're careful to do a fresh download/unzip.
But it looks like the .bin file alone is over 7GB in size. The RAM required to successfully complete a load of that model will thus be at least that large. Still, if your RAM is insufficient you'd just get memory errors (or extreme slowness if your system falls back to virtual memory) - not decoding errors.
You may need to switch to a smaller model. But if you're still getting decoding errors, expand your question with updated exact details of which download-expand-code steps trigger the errors.
